# getting error in openalpr libarary in java

Tags: android

I am using OpenAlpr library when i want to scan number plate. but i getting error as below image:

Could not find com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.1.0-alpha01

https://github.com/sujaybhowmick/OpenAlprDroidApp using this library.

[image]

i need any suggestion or solution, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Install-Package libmi -Version 1.0.0-alpha01
```

Source https://powershell.myget.org/F/powershell-core/api/v3/index.json